# I would like to work out the distance of data points (lat/long) from the edges of a shape file in R and then apply a criterion to the data points?

Tags: r, distance

I have data points of a species observed using camera traps and would like to measure the distance of each camera trap site (CameraStation) to the edge of a national park using R. I have a shapefile of the park (shp) and want to apply a criterion to CameraStation(s) which are <5km from the edge. My data frame (df) consists of multiple events/observations (EventID) per CameraStation. The aim is to analyse when events near the park edge are most frequent given other environmental factors such as Season, Moon Phase and DayNight (also columns in DF).

I found a package called `distance` in `R` but this is for distance sampling and not what I want to do. Which package is relevant in this situation?

I expect the following outcome:

```
EventID  CameraStation  Distance(km)  Within 5km
0001     Station 1      4.3           Yes
0002     Station 1      4.3           Yes
0003     Station 2      16.2          No
0004     Station 3      0.5           Yes
...
```

Comment: I think you question may have already been answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225102/calculate-distance-between-points-and-nearest-polygon-in-r).

Comment: Hi Gregory. I had a look at the link you sent me. Thank you for your suggestion. It looks very complicated, but form what I can comprehend this only gives distances from points outside the polygon. I have points inside (apart from 1 which happens to be outside). Is there a more simple way which measures from inside the polygon to the edges?

Comment: I'm working on a solution for you. Check back later.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general solution, adapted from Spacedmans answer to [this question at gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225102/calculate-distance-between-points-and-nearest-polygon-in-r). *Note:* This solution requires working in a projected coordinate system. You can transform to a projected CRS if needed using `spTransform`.

The `gDistance` function of the rgeos package calculates the distance between geometries, but for the case of points inside a polygon the distance is zero. The trick is to create a new "mask" polygon where the original polygon is a hole cut out from the mask. Then we can measure the distance between points in the hole and the mask, which is the distance to the edge of the original polygon that we really care about.

We'll use the shape file of the Yellowstone National Park Boundary found on [this page](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4ffb3aebe4b0c15d5ce9fc0b).

```
library(sp) # for SpatialPoints and proj4string
library(rgdal) # to read shapefile with readOGR
library(rgeos) # for gDistance, gDifference, and gBuffer

# ab67 was the name of the shape file I downloaded.
yellowstone.shp <- readOGR("ab67")

# gBuffer enlarges the boundary of the polygon by the amount specified by `width`.
# The units of `width` (meters in this case) can be found in the proj4string 
# for the polygon.
yellowstone_buffer <- gBuffer(yellowstone.shp, width = 5000)

# gDifference calculates the difference between the polygons, i.e. what's
# in one and not in the other. That's our mask.
mask <- gDifference(yellowstone_buffer, yellowstone.shp)

# Some points inside the park
pts <- list(x = c(536587.281264245, 507432.037861251, 542517.161278414,
                  477782.637790409, 517315.171218198),
            y = c(85158.0056377799, 77251.498952222, 15976.0721391485,
                  40683.9055315169, -3790.19457474617))

# Sanity checking the mask and our points.
plot(mask)
points(pts)
```

[image]

```
# Put the points in a SpatialPointsDataFrame with camera id in a data field.
spts.df <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, data = data.frame(Camera = ordered(1:length(pts$x))))

# Give our SpatialPointsDataFrame the same spatial reference as the polygon.
proj4string(spts.df) <- proj4string(yellowstone.shp)

# Calculate distances (km) from points to edge and put in a new column.
spts.df$km_to_edge <- apply(gDistance(spts.df, difference, byid=TRUE),2,min)/1000

# Determine which records are within 5 km of an edge and note in new column.
spts.df$edge <- ifelse(spts.df$km_to_edge < 5, TRUE, FALSE)

# Results
spts.df

#             coordinates Camera km_to_edge  edge
# 1  (536587.3, 85158.01)      1   1.855010  TRUE
# 2     (507432, 77251.5)      2   9.762755 FALSE
# 3  (542517.2, 15976.07)      3  11.668700 FALSE
# 4  (477782.6, 40683.91)      4   4.579638  TRUE
# 5 (517315.2, -3790.195)      5   8.211961 FALSE
```

Comment: This worked, however, I have strange values for my km_to_egde. I get many 0s or a few 500km to the edge and this isn't representative of the data - even though when I 'sanity checked' the points and mask they are right. Why would this be? I am using the same CRS for both points and mask (CRS("+init=EPSG:32648")). Also, my data is across 2 grid zones UTM 47N and UTM 48N, but only data points in UTM 48N appear. I think I will have to do this twice for each Grid Zone and add them to one data frame after.

Comment: I redid the code for the CRS("+init=EPSG:32647") to correspond with the UTM 47 Grid Zone and this time I get many 500+ km_to_edge and a few 0s... it has inverted the 0s and 500s from before. It seems to measuring to the edge of the Grid Zone and not the park?? I will look into this further.

Comment: Without a reproducible example of your problem (data and code), it's hard to know what's happening. I suspect you are having CRS issues, though, possibly related to having multiple UTM grids. [EPSG:32648](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32648/prettywkt/) is only for UTM 48N.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution.

Simplify the outline of your shapefile into N points. Then calculate the minimum distance for each camera trap to every point in the outline of the national park.

```
library(geosphrere)
n      <- 500 ##The number of points summarizing the shapefile
NPs    <- ##Your shapefile goes here
NP.pts <- spsample(NPs, n = n, type = "regular")


CP.pts <- ## Coordinates for a single trap
distances<-distm(coordinates(CP.pts), coordinates(NP.pts), fun = distHaversine)/1000 

##Distance in Km between the trap to each point in the perimeter of the shapefile:
distances
```

Use `distances` to find the minimum distance between the shapefile and that given trap. This approach can easily be generalizable using for `loops` or `apply` functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got this error when I ran this code.  ``` > NP.pts <- spsample(NPs, n = n, type = "regular") ```
Error in n * bb.area : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the points data frame and shape file being projected so instead I used the example in this link to answer my question

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225102/calculate-distance-between-points-and-nearest-polygon-in-r

Basically, I used this code;

```
df # my data frame with points
shp # my shapefile (non-projected)

dist.mat <- geosphere::dist2Line(p = df2, line = shp)
coordinates(df2)<-~Longitude+Latitude # Longitude and Latitude are columns in my df

dmat<-data.frame(dist.mat) # turned it into a data frame

dmat$km5 <- ifelse(dmat$distance < 5000, TRUE, FALSE) # in meters (5000)
coordinates(dmat)<-~lon+lat

df2$distance <- dmat$distance # added new Distance column to my df
```